# Is this HTTP request valid?

Tags: python, http, go, httprequest, swagger

I've made an python server with `swagger-codegen`. I have one endpoint that receives an file with `mutlipart/form-data`

And also created an client with [go-swagger](https://github.com/go-swagger/go-swagger) for testing.

created an file to upload: `$ echo "123file content321" > data`

and used the client to upload the file to the server. The resulting HTTP request looks like this:

```
POST /api/order/1/attachment HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=5f3f0ad86e6345b77c869cbe0a5e608f038354cf9ceab74ec2533d7555c0
Accept-Encoding: gzip

ff
--5f3f0ad86e6345b77c869cbe0a5e608f038354cf9ceab74ec2533d7555c0
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="data"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

123file content321

--5f3f0ad86e6345b77c869cbe0a5e608f038354cf9ceab74ec2533d7555c0--
```

but the server doesn't accept it and responds:

```
HTTP/1.0 400 BAD REQUEST
Connection: close
Content-Length: 120
Content-Type: application/problem+json
Date: Fri, 19 May 2017 15:15:44 GMT
Server: Werkzeug/0.12.1 Python/3.6.1
{
  "type": "about:blank",
  "title": "Bad Request",
  "detail": "Missing formdata parameter 'file'",
  "status": 400
}
```

So the request isn't parsed properly. But when I use the swagger-ui, the file is uploaded correctly. Is there problem with the client's request, or the server has a problem?

EDIT: I think that there is missing `Content-Lenght` or the `ff` at the beginning of the BODY might not be there

EDIT2: the swagger-ui request:

```
POST /api/order/1/attachment HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 211
Origin: http://localhost:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarypzmNwrDR7zzpZ7SJ
Accept: application/json
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
DNT: 1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

------WebKitFormBoundarypzmNwrDR7zzpZ7SJ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="data"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

123file content321

------WebKitFormBoundarypzmNwrDR7zzpZ7SJ--
```

Comment: The client and server need to negotiate between HTTP 1.1 and 1.0, because the server is using HTTP 1.0; if you have control of the server, just add the property `protocol_version = "HTTP/1.1"` to your BaseHTTPRequestHandler subclass (see https://github.com/mineralsprings/json-api-host/blob/master/server.py#L26)

Comment: `"detail": "Missing formdata parameter 'file'"` seems to want it to be `file="name"` not `name="file"`

Comment: name="file" is correct, I think, because that is the name of the form parameter.

I've missed that HTTP version mismatch. I run the test server with `python -m swagger_server` can I add some parameter to run the `BaseHTTPServer` with `HTTP/1.1`? Or somehow configure the flask framework?

Comment: Well, we need the source of the server to know why it thinks that's a bad request, because I think it's well formed.

Comment: If you're using flask, the flask documentation surely talks about setting the server version, but it may not be overly important

Comment: so I've set `http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler.protocol_version = "HTTP/1.1"` and the server now responds with `HTTP/1.1` but the result is the same. The code isn't interesting, it is just `connexion` that loads the `swagger.yaml`

Comment: Can you post the request that is being sent by the swagger-ui for comparison? Open up dev tools and look at the request. That'll probably shed some light on this.

Answer (score 2):

The first request you send is a HTTP/1.1 request using chunked transfer encoding. This means the body is consisting of multiple chunks where each chunk is prefixed by the size in hex followed by `\r\n` followed by the data and again `\r\n`. I'm not sure if the `ff` at the beginning of the body you show really specifies the size of the following data (i.e. 255 bytes). But, the last chunk with a size of 0 is missing, so this request is incomplete. But maybe you just omitted the missing part from this question only.

Apart from that the server is responding with version HTTP/1.0. Chunked transfer encoding is only defined for HTTP/1.1 which means that this request will not be understood by a HTTP/1.0 server. And not even all HTTP/1.1 server will understand chunked transfer encoding in the request even if they should.

The second request you show (created by Chrome) does not use chunked transfer encoding but specifies instead the length of the header using `Content-length` in the HTTP header. That's the way you should go since this works with all web  servers,  including HTTP/1.0 servers.

Comment: the last 0 chunk was there, but I didn't know that the 0 is a part of the request. I must now find out how to tell to the go http client to not use http chunked transfer. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the two requests you have posted I would attempt to set the `Content-Length` on your go request first and test that. I've run into issues before with the ArangoDB HTTP API not accepting requests without a correct content length value.

If the succeeds then yay.

Otherwise, that `ff` in your request is the next thing I'd look at getting rid of. But I'd focus on the `Content-Length` header first.